Geometric realization of polygonal presentation (as in Lee)
The below excerpt is from Lees "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" (p. 168):

I have a hard time interpreting exactly what is meant by this sentence with respect to exactly what the equivalence relation/what we are quoting with? Why "vertices" in plural?
Let's say we have $$\langle a,b,c,e,f \;|\; ab^{-1}c^{-1}, bcf \rangle.$$ Then what exactly should be "glued" (geometrically) together here? If I start with $a$ in $ab^{-1}c^{-1}$, there is no corresponding $a^{-1}$ in $bcf$. Should I then move on to $b^{-1}$ and glue it together with the only occurence with $b$ in $bcf$ (viewed as edges in their respctive triangles), and then do the same for $c^{-1}$ in $W_1 = ab^{-1}c^{-1}$ with $c$ in $W_2 = bcf$? Or should I only take elements that are not inverses and perform the given operation?
Just to be clear, I am thinking of $ab^{-1}c^{-1}$ and $bcf$ as the two triangles below:
What is the general "algorithm" here?
When the gluing happens, I suppose I must take into account how the directions on the edges might change as I perform affine homeomorphisms to make the gluing operations possible? Take for example the gluing of $b^{-1}$ with $b$. I suppose this will look something like below (I am perhaps wildly off)?


Oh, ok, I do think I understand what he says now, he is just talking about how to match up $a$ and $a^{-1}$ for some $a \in S$ for a polygonal presentation $\mathcal{P} = \langle S ;|\ W_1,\ldots,W_k \rangle$. But what if there is one $a$ in $W_1$ and two $a^{-1}$s in $W_2$, for example?
